# Dificulties in modifying or duplicating a view

Tags: views, 8

I'm using drupal 8 (it seems to me exact version is 8.1.8) as CMS. 
I created many views, and I would like to modify them o to duplicate those views.
But, mainly after I set a contextual filter, is not possible to modify the view.

And I 'm experiencing troubles too in duplicate a view and then modify the parameters.

Is there any know issue about those difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple views, have you considered using additional displays from the base view instead? That way they can share common configuration, but you can do things like apply a contextual filter to just certain displays.

Comment: This is a good idea, but seems that after setting a contextual filter modifications aren't allow any more, neither in new additional displays...